# how do I minus 2 days from current day while sending mail through outlook by using Excel

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I want to minus 2 days from current day while sending mail ( need to place date in subject)through outlook by using excel vba

Comment: Please include the details of what you have tried so far.

Comment: .Subject = "EKL (Logistics) Sales update week ending" & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy") - dd.AddDays(-2)

Comment: Subject = "EKL (Logistics) Sales update week ending" & " " & Format(Now-2, "dd-mmm-yy")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this.

```
Option Explicit
Sub AddDate()
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olMail As Object
    Dim SubjectDate As String

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

    SubjectDate = Format(Now - 2, "Long Date")
'                               OR
'                                  "Short Date"
'                                  "DD/MM/YYYY"
'
    With olMail
        .Subject = SubjectDate
        .Display
    End With

    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865652(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class which allows to get or set a string indicating the subject for the Outlook item.

The [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) article explains all the required steps for automating Outlook.

Comment: Thank for the link but i need the small one here only to subract two days from the currrent date